# MySQL user is taking more than 100% of CPU utilization

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

My CPU% is more than 130%  but i haven;t created any user with name "MYSQL"

Here is what i am getting

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRr3x.png)

Comment: What utility produced that output?  How many cores?  Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

In your WHM the OWNER column indicates either (a user account or system account that started the process)

So the MYSQL Process is a system owned service

To troubleshoot its CPU spike, Check the  mysql processlist for currently running queries.